# Getting a System.IO.FileNotFoundException when launching an .exe

Tags: windows-7, event-viewer

When I try to start a .exe I'm just getting the "The program has stopped to work" dialog (I have the computer in Italian so I do not know the English localized name). When I see the event viewer for information that's what I'm getting:

```
Bucket errato 1874742253, tipo 5
Nome evento: CLR20r3
Risposta: Non disponibile
ID CAB: 0

Firma problema:
P1: qbegenerator.exe
P2: 7.2.1.17
P3: 4d9dc78e
P4: QBEGenerator
P5: 7.2.1.17
P6: 4d9dc78e
P7: 200
P8: 50
P9: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
P10: 

File allegati:
C:\Users\eianni\AppData\Local\Temp\WER89F6.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

I file potrebbero essere disponibili qui:
C:\Users\eianni\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_qbegenerator.exe_e38c802972b17e7f6ff0b9ab2eac7df8a5fcb8f8_07378ec7

Simbolo analisi: 
Nuova ricerca di soluzioni: 0
ID rapporto: 599e43dc-ee77-11e0-8067-8c736eaf5d85
Stato rapporto: 0
```

Despite the Italian what is important is `P9: System.IO.FileNotFoundException`. Now...where is the missing filename? How could I solve the problem if I do not know what file is not found?
If you need translation just comment the question.

Comment: I'd say `C:\Users\eianni\AppData\Local\Temp\WER89F6.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml` was the missing file

Comment: It says attached files and that seems a report to me.

Comment: @dierre: It may be possible to debug the program. If you install the Visual Studio 2010 trial version (http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/try) I believe you will be prompted to debug when it crashes and a more detailed error should appear.

Comment: I would second @James's answer, but failing that can you open the XML file that is referenced (before it gets uploaded) and see if that has any details in it?

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2005 on my machine but it's not prompting. I expected that but it's not happpening.

Comment: Do you not get the "Debug the program" button at all?  Which version of Visual Studio 2005 do you have (Express, Ultimate etc.)?

Comment: Nope, I can't choose, when I open a project, an exe file. I have the pro edition with C#, Basic,Web Developer, but no C++

Comment: Did you try opening _C:\Users\eianni\AppData\Local\Temp\WER89F6.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml_ file and see what's in it? Maybe you could find some sort of description...

Comment: @dierre: I still think it's worth installing the VS2010 trial - hopefully the "Debug the program" button should become visible.